# Should one use rake db:migrate when you have mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, devise-confirmable

I am creating a new migration like this:

```
rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise
```

And it is generating the file in: `db/migrate/YYYYMMDDxxx_add_confirmable_to_devise.rb`

and I add this:

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # Note: You can't use change, as User.update_all will fail in the down migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    # add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string # Only if using reconfirmable
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, unique: true
    # User.reset_column_information # Need for some types of updates, but not for update_all.
    # To avoid a short time window between running the migration and updating all existing
    # users as confirmed, do the following
    User.update_all confirmed_at: DateTime.now
    # All existing user accounts should be able to log in after this.
  end

  def down
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
    # remove_columns :users, :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
  end
end
```

and then I do `rake db:migrate`

I get that `Process finished with exit code 0`

but when I try to test it to sign up I get: `undefined local variable or method 'confirmed_at' for #User`

I am following these instruction [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users)

Is it because I have mongodb? Is it done differently in mongodb?

Comment: You don't use migrations with Mongo, you only need to configure the fields on the model and you are done. Migrations are used for SQL databases.

Comment: @arieljuod Except the `User.update_all confirmed_at: DateTime.now` part, you'd need to patch that part of the database up by hand, no?

Comment: @muistooshort, yeap, that's not a change on the scrutrure of a table it's just to set a default value to all previous users. It's only needed if you already have users and you want them to be flagged as confirmed, but if you are just starting to develop and have no users yet then there's no need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

Taken from [RailsApp GitHub Issue](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-omniauth/issues/2):

> **When you use Mongoid and MongoDB, there is no need to run rake `db:migrate`**. An advantage of using MongoDB is there is no need for migrations or schemas.

From [Mongo Doc:](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/getting-started-rails/#adjust-models)

> Mongoid does not utilize ActiveRecord migrations, since MongoDB does not require a schema to be defined prior to storing data.

When using MongoDB, you only need to configure the fields on the model. Migrations (and Schemas) are used for SQL databases.